# "Request method 'POST' not supported". Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

When I'm trying to do POST  method I'm always getting the following error:

> {"status": 405
>   "error": "Method Not Allowed"
>   "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException"
>   "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported"
>   "path": "/api/items" }

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class ItemController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemController.class);
    private final ItemService service;

    @Autowired
    public ItemController(ItemService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    ItemDto create(@RequestBody @Valid ItemDto item) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating item={}", item);
        return service.create(item);
    }    
}

@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String> {}

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItemServiceImpl.class);
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ItemServiceImpl(ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public ItemDto create(ItemDto item) {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        LOGGER.debug("Creating new item={}, date={}", item, date);

        Item persisted = Item.getItemBuilder(item.getTitle(), item.getPrice(), item.getDescription())
                .withCategory(item.getCategory())
                .withOwner(item.getOwner())
                .withPhotos(item.getPhotoURLs())
                .withState(item.getState())
                .withDate(date)
                .build();
        itemRepository.save(persisted);
        return convertToDto(persisted);
    }
```

Do you know why and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding value to path for **create()** method '@RequestMapping(**value="create"**, method = RequestMethod.POST)'. URL='api/items/create'

Comment: take a look at [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers), try like that

Comment: hmm.. I added. And it works when I do POST on api/items, but when I do POST on api/items/create I' getting the same error.

Comment: Use `@RequestMapping(value="/create" method = RequestMethod.POST)` for the method annotation when you want to access it by `api/items/create` - if still only the old url work, then it is likely that you have an deployment problem.

Comment: It seems strange.. After adding `@RequestMapping(value="/create" method = RequestMethod.POST)`, when I do POST on api/items/  it works, on api/items/create doesn't work, and surprisingly when I do PUT method on api/items/create it works, but my PUT looks: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)`